# Laravel eloquent compare two withCount values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a query where I compare two counts on the same relationship and I only want to see the entries when booth counts are the same.

First I'm counting all relationship and the second count has a condition:

```
$query->withCount([
'RequirementRequestPositions',
'RequirementRequestPositions as requirement_request_positions_invoiced_count' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('invoiced_at', '!=', null);
                }
            ]);
```

I'm getting the correct count of requirement_request_positions_count and also the correct count of requirement_request_positions_invoiced_count

But now I want only have the entries if booth counts are the same. I have tried something like this:

```
$query->having('requirement_request_positions_count', '=', 'requirement_request_positions_invoiced_count');
```

I don't get an error, but the result isn't correct. If I set the second value by hand, for example 5, then it's working. What would be the proper way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking to far. I could just do something like this. No need to use the count for this:

```
            $query->whereHas('RequirementRequestPositions', function ($q) {
            $q->where('invoiced_at', '=', null);
        });
```